# How to select all project except two or three project in Package Manager Console

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have a fairly large solution which has about 150 projects. I want to reinstall all packages via Package Manager Console.

I can select any types of packages using `Get-Project` and with wild char name. For example for selecting all test projects I use

```
Get-Project CompanyName.ProjectName.*.Tests
```

But currently, I am interested to select all projects except some of them. Say I want to skip three projects called `CompanyName.ProjectA`, `CompanyName.ProjectB` and `CompanyName.ProjectC`. How can I select all projects except those three?

I am using Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, the current version of your answer couldn't provide actual project list in actual format. Hence your command followed by `| Update-Package -Reinstall` not working in package manager console directly. Anyway, I have solved my problem by filtering with Solution Folder. And hence, I have not tried to tweak your answer to get the desired output. Thanks for helping me, hopefully, your answer will help me a lot in near future.

Comment: That is OK. Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, would you please share your solution as answer, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread, thanks.

Comment: I have not submitted my solution because it is not a correct answer of my question, but as it somehow solved my actual problem, It may solve some others problem as well.

Instead of selecting project by project name I have selected project by Solution Folder name. As I had only 6 top level solution folder and filtering those project my solution folder was easy for my case and it works fine. For example, to select all Projects under Microservices Solution folder I have used `Get-Project Microservices` command followed by `| Update-Package -Reinstall` to reinstall all packages.

Answer (score 0):

> How to select all project except two or three project in Package Manager Console

As we know, The Package Manager Console provides a PowerShell interface within Visual Studio on Windows to interact with NuGet through the specific commands listed. So we could also use the PowerShell command line on the Package Manager Console. You can use following command line with option `-inotmatch` all projects except those three:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter "*.csproj").name -inotmatch 'CompanyName.ProjectA|CompanyName.ProjectB|CompanyName.ProjectC'
```

Check [PowerShell reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/powershell-reference) for some details.

Hope this helps.